# API design for loading OpenGL textures asynchronously

Tags: c++, asynchronous, api, opengl

What do you think about this API for loading OpenGL textures asynchronously?

My main concern is that the loader class executes code on the client io_service. This takes away some control from the user but should be convenient in most scenarios.

I'm also thinking about using a texture on the stack and a shared_ptr that can be disregarded when the texture is fully loaded. Not sure if this is necessary.

Criticism and suggestions of any sort are very welcome.

```
class loader {
public:
  using open_handler = function<void(error_code ec, shared_ptr<istream> is, image image)>;
  using read_handler = function<void(error_code ec)>;

  loader(io_service& client_service) : client_service_(client_service) {
    // Start a thread that creates a second OpenGL context and executes service_.run().
  }

  void open(filesystem::path path, open_handler handler) {
    service_.post([this, path(move(path)), handler(move(handler))]() mutable {
      shared_ptr<istream> is = make_shared<ifstream>(/* Open the image. */);
      image image({ 100, 100, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE }); /* Read the size/format information. */;
      on_open(error_code(), std::move(handler), std::move(is), std::move(image));
    });
  }

  void on_open(error_code ec, open_handler handler, shared_ptr<istream> is, image image) {
    client_service_.post([handler(move(handler)), is(move(is)), image(move(image))]() {
      handler(error_code(), move(is), move(image));
    });
  }

  void read(weak_ptr<texture> texture, GLenum format, GLenum type, shared_ptr<istream> is, read_handler handler) {
    service_.post([this, texture, format, type, is(move(is)), handler(move(handler))]() mutable {
      // Read the image, scaling and converting it. Update the texture with every new line of pixels.
      client_service_.post([handler(move(handler))]() {
        handler(error_code());
      });
    });
  }

private:
  io_service service_;
  io_service& client_service_;
};

class client {
public:
  client() : loader_(service_) {
  }

  void create() {
    // Create the main window OpenGL context.
    loader_.open("/path/to/file.png", [this](error_code ec, shared_ptr<istream> is, image image) {
      texture_ = make_shared<texture>(0 /* Create a new texture. */, image.cx / 2, image.cy / 2);
      // Create a VBO/VAO and assign the texture.
      loader_.read(texture_, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, move(is), [this](error_code ec) {
        throw runtime_error("...");  // will be thrown on service_.poll() call in draw().
      });
    });
  }

  void draw() {
    service_.poll();
    // Draw to the context and swap.
  }

private:
  io_service service_;
  loader loader_;
  shared_ptr<texture> texture_;
};
```

Here is a link to wandbox to play around with the code: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bEcpM340KgU6hY5V